# Virtual Hosts not working or redirecting in WAMP

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, localhost, wamp

I have a problem that only takes place in Google Chrome and it is OK in Firefox and IE.
I have googled a lot of websites and done a few tips but nothing worked.

I have WAMP Server installed. I have setup two virtual hosts:

The problem is that whenever I enter localhost in the addressbar, It immediately redirects to enginter.local !
And Chrome shows this error for all of local URLs:

> This page isn’t working
>
> enginter.local didn’t send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

`httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/real/yegane"
    ServerName yegane.local
    ServerAlias www.yegane.local
    ErrorLog "logs/yegane.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/yegane.local-access.log" common
    <Directory "/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/real/enginter"
    ServerName enginter.local
    ServerAlias www.enginter.local
    ErrorLog "logs/enginter.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/enginter.local-access.log" common
    <Directory "/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my `hosts` file (in Windows 10):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#::1            localhost

127.0.0.1   enginter.local
127.0.0.1   yegane.local
```

I tried clearing the DNS cache here chrome://net-internals/#dns And also tried resetting everything to default in chrome://flags but no luck!

Once I restarted the system and the problem was gone. but after a while it happened again. And also port 80 is used by Apache.

I'm sorry if it's confusing. I'm confused myself and it has taken my time for a whole week.

**UPDATE**

Now all of my browsers are doing this!

**UPDATE 2**

`httpd -S` gives:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:*            is a NameVirtualHost
         default server enginter.local (D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:43)
         port * namevhost enginter.local (D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:43)
                 alias www.enginter.local
         port * namevhost yegane.local (D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:57)
                 alias www.yegane.local
*:80                   localhost (D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:30)
ServerRoot: "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23"
Main DocumentRoot: "D:/wamp/www"
Main ErrorLog: "D:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"
Mutex default: dir="D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/logs/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: APACHE24=Apache2.4
Define: VERSION_APACHE=2.4.23
Define: INSTALL_DIR=D:/wamp
Define: APACHE_DIR=D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23
```

Comment: Your `ServerAlias` entries do not match the `hosts` entries. One has `www` the other doesn't.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks. Now I commented the `ServerAlias` entries and added a new virtual host with `ServerName` of `localhost` (pointing to www directory). Now What happens is this: Contents of `yegane,local` and `enginter,local` are shown but the request for `localhost` redirects (instantly) to `enginter.local`

Comment: *shrug* I told you what was wrong and you appear to have made some other change ...

Comment: Any "localhost" virtual host should be first (before either of the other host entries). ServerAlias for your second and third hosts should appear exactly as listed in your original question example (i.e. www.example.local and uncommented).

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry I though that you're saying `ServerAlias` makes that change mandatory so I commented it. Now I did as you said and added `www.*.local` (* for each virtual host) But nothing changed. Again, `localhost` redirects to `enginter.local`

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thank you my friend. I moved the virtual host with `ServerName` of `localhost` to the end of the file and uncommented the `ServerAlias` entries and also added those aliases to my `hosts` file. Again nothing has changed and `localhost` redirects to `enginter.local`. Would it be a cache problem in my system?!

Comment: Perhaps. If it was a caching issue, it would most likely be with the browser. Just as a suggestion, though, I would move the "localhost" entry back to the top. This should help ensure that this is the first host checked.

Comment: If you did decide to flush anything else besides the browser, you would probably want to do the Windows DNS cache.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks. I moved the entry for `localhost` to the top (although there is `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` for localhost in the main `httpd.conf` file too) and cleared windows's dns cache. no luck!

Comment: I have posted an answer. While I am not certain it will help totally with your case, I think it will ensure we're on the same page. I have tested the entry with Chrome, it works, and there should be no issue. If there is, I will glad to continue to help but it may not be something easily resolvable.

Answer (score 0):

I would structure your virtual host entries in `httpd-vhosts.conf` as follows:

```
# Assuming we wish to type in e.g. "localhost" in Chrome

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName localhost
    #ServerAlias should be unneeded 
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/real/localhost"  # Or whatever directory is appropriated
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/locahost.local-access.log" common
    #... Other stuff ...
</VirtualHost>

#... Other entries as listed ...
```

Note that `#... Other stuff ...` can obviously be `Directory` information or anything else you wish to include but is not required. This configuration *should* give you access to "localhost" in your browser by either typing "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

> There is are ServerName and DocumentRoot entries for localhost in the main httpd.conf file, too[.]

You shouldn't need to change anything about the `DocumentRoot` in `httpd.conf` but you should change the *ServerName* entry in `httpd.conf`, specifically to something *other* than "localhost" (e.g. `ServerName MyCoolServer` =P).

You will (of course) want to restart your WAMP (Apache) server and flush your browser cache (you may even want to do it twice). In Chrome you can use *chrome://settings/clearBrowserData*.
Similar results in Firefox can be achieved with the *History - > Clear History... * options (clear at least the *Browsing & Download History* and *Cache* settings from the earliest time possible from the drop down).

Comment: Thanks man. Now chrome is OK and Firefox has that problem -_- . I flushed  the DNS several times. I've done many changes to `httpd-vhosts.conf` and still the problem exists!!

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate. It worked fine with Firefox in my tests, so perhaps it is browser caching. I would use the same setup as above and but use `History -> Clear Recent History` in Firefox. I would select at least the "Browsing..", "Cookies" & "Cache" entries and make sure the time drop down was set to "From The Beginning Of Time" (or whatever the earliest selection is).